# Подсчитать количество измененных объектов для разных пользователей

Tags: mysql, sql

Всем привет, вопрос такой, как мне подсчитать количество измененных объектов (obj_type) для каждого пользователя (user), где event_type = 2 и obj_id не дублируется для user?

Имеется таблица такого вида:

| event_type | user | obj_type | obj_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Василий Васильев | 2 | 2000 |
| 2 | Василий Васильев | 2 | 2000 |
| 2 | Василий Васильев | 2 | 2000 |
| 2 | Василий Васильев | 2 | 2001 |
| 2 | Василий Васильев | 4 | 4000 |
| 2 | Владимир Владимиров | 1 | 1000 |
| 2 | Владимир Владимиров | 4 | 4000 |
| 2 | Петр Петров | 3 | 3000 |
| 2 | Петр Петров | 3 | 3000 |

Вот какой результат необходим:

| user | Count obj_type 1 | Count obj_type 2 | Count obj_type 3 | Count obj_type 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Василий Васильев | 0 | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| Владимир Владимиров | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Петр Петров | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

Имеется такой запрос, но он работает только если нет повторных obj_id, в противном случае он просто посчитает все obj_type для этого user

```
SELECT
       user,
       sl_name,
       `len`,
       count(case when obj_type=1 then 1 end) as "countCouple",
       count(case when obj_type=2 then 1 end) as "countBoxPon",
       count(case when obj_type=3 then 1 end) as "countOpticCross",
       count(case when obj_type=4 then 1 end) as "countNode"
       FROM logObj
       WHERE event_type = 1
       GROUP BY user, sl_name
```

Количество типов объектов(obj_type) - фиксированное

Comment: `count(distinct case when obj_type=1 then obj_id end)`

Comment: Да, работает, спасибо! Но не могли бы вы оставить как ответ на вопрос, а не комментарий? Чтобы я мог отметить решение, вдруг в будущем у кого-то такой же вопрос будет

Comment: Думаю, будет правильно, если Вы напишете само-ответ, но дополните его подробным объяснением, почему именно так. В порядке "три раза объяснил, уже и сам понял...", ну и как оплату за помощь :)